# No default constructor exists for class but I have declared one

Tags: c++, default-constructor

I have this occur twice in my code,
I'm not sure why it's complaining
I have a header file "Scene.h":

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "Image.h"
#include "InteractiveObject.h"

using namespace std;

    class Scene
    {
    public:
        int id;
        string title;
        Image* backgroundImage;
        InteractiveObject interactiveObjects[ 1 ];

        D3DXVECTOR3 pos;

        Scene( int id_, string title_, Image* backgroundImage_ )
            : 
            id( id_ ),
            title( title_ ),
            backgroundImage( backgroundImage_ )
        {
            this->pos.x = 0.0f;
            this->pos.y = 0.0f;
            this->pos.z = 0.0f;
        }
    };
```

I have another file called "InteractiveObject.h":

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "Image.h"
enum { CHARACTER, OBJECT };

class InteractiveObject
{
public:
    int id;
    int type;

    float x;
    float y;
    float z;

    D3DXVECTOR3 pos;

    string title;
    Image* theImage;
    InteractiveObject( int id_, string title_, Image* theImage_, int type, float x, float y, float z )
        : 
        id( id_ ),
        title( title_ ),
        theImage( theImage_ )
    {
        this->pos.x = x;
        this->pos.y = y;
        this->pos.z = z;
    }
};
```

My intellisense is complaining that there is:

> Error 1   error C2512: 'InteractiveObject' : no appropriate default
>   constructor available c:\users\james\documents\visual studio
>   2012\projects\game\game\scene.h   26  1   Game

Any ideas considering both have default constructors?

EDIT::----------

Okay so thanks to everyone here, I can see that if I do this:;

```
InteractiveObject( int id_, string title_, Image* theImage_, int type_, float x_, float y_, float z_ )
        : 
        id( id_ ),
        title( title_ ),
        theImage( theImage_ ),
        type( type_ ),
        x( x_ ),
        y( y_ ),
        z( z_ )
    {
```

The problem disappears.. I'm not sure this is the best way of doing it and I will no doubt come back crying in a few moments. Can you please vote the answer that delivers what you think is the most concise answer?

My current requirement is to have a Scene contain a certain amount of interactive objects declared on my game constructor and iterated over to draw to the screen:

"game.cpp":

```
Game::Game( HWND hWnd, Mouse &mouse  )
    :
    gfx( hWnd ),
    mouse( mouse )
{
    gfx.d3dDevice->SetRenderState( D3DRS_ALPHABLENDENABLE, TRUE);

    //--------------Scene 0---------------
    scenes[ 0 ] = Scene( 0, "La barra de funk", new Image( gfx, "Images/Scene/Area/Bar/Background.jpg", 1024, 768, FALSE ) );
    scenes[ 0 ].interactiveObjects[ 0 ] = new InteractiveObject( 0, "la rockola de muse", new Image( gfx, "Images/Scene/Area/Bar/InteractiveObjects/Jukebox.png", 428, 586, TRUE ), OBJECT, 300.0f, 200.0f, 1.0f );
};

Game::~Game()
{
    // Delete scenes array

    /*for( int a = 0; a < sizeof( scenes ) / sizeof( Scene ); a++ )
    {
        scenes[ a ] = NULL;
        delete scenes[ a ];
    }*/
};

void Game::Go()
{
    gfx.Begin();
    ComposeFrame();
    gfx.End();
    gfx.Present();
};

void Game::ComposeFrame()
{
    for each ( Scene currentScene in scenes )
    {
        currentScene.backgroundImage->sprite->Begin( D3DXSPRITE_ALPHABLEND );
        currentScene.backgroundImage->sprite->Draw( currentScene.backgroundImage->gTexture, NULL, NULL, &currentScene.pos, 0xFFFFFFFF );
        currentScene.backgroundImage->sprite->End();

        for each ( InteractiveObject currentInteractiveObject in currentScene.interactiveObjects )
        {
            currentInteractiveObject.theImage->sprite->Begin( D3DXSPRITE_ALPHABLEND );
            currentInteractiveObject.theImage->sprite->Draw( currentScene.backgroundImage->gTexture, NULL, NULL, &currentInteractiveObject.pos, 0xFFFFFFFF );
            currentInteractiveObject.theImage->sprite->End();
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: `InteractiveObject interactiveObjects[ 1 ];` How are you expecting this to work exactly? How would it create an `InteractiveObject`?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - Could you check out my last edit (the bottom bit of code)... I am realtively new to c++, I was attempting to create a scene and then push interactive objects into it in my game constructor.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - Meh, I changed it all to pointers, works like a charm brah!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A default constructor doesn't require any arguments passed to it, either because it doesn't take any arguments, or there are default values for all of the named parameters.  From your code, the `InteractiveObject` class' constructor required parameters, but it's also constructed in your `Scene` class when you call

```
InteractiveObject interactiveObjects[ 1 ];
```

You could either dynamically create this (using `new`), or add a non-argument constructor to the `InteractiveObject` class.

Comment: Thanks to everyone... I think I get it, I'm going to come back and see if I can get it to work... bear with me

Answer (score 3):

Your classes have *non-default* constructors (that is, constructors which take arguments).  They do not have *default* constructors, which take zero arguments.

One of the requirements for placing objects into C arrays are that the objects be default constructable.  Otherwise, the compiler has no way to construct them -- when you declare an array, the compiler is required to default-construct all of the instances in the array (there is no way to pass constructor arguments to objects in an array).

To fix this, you either need to make sure you never use those classes in arrays (e.g. you can replace all object arrays by arrays of pointers, if you wish, but then memory management becomes harder).  Alternatively, just add simple default constructors which initialize all of the class members to reasonable values.

Comment: The reason I didn't use pointers is that I wanted to use the foreach function for c++ :( is that a bad choice perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Since:

```
InteractiveObject interactiveObjects[ 1 ];
```

It will call `default constructor` of class `InteractiveObject`. However, the constructor you have provided does not meet `default constructor` since:

```
1. it has arguments
2. all of its arguments does not have default values.
```

so that constructor cannot be treated as `default constructor`, in a sense that it cannot be called without providing any parameter. For this reason, the compiler cannot generate one `default constructor` for you, so you have that error.

Answer (score 0):

```
InteractiveObject( int id_, string title_, Image* theImage_, int type, float x, float y, float z )
```

You need to put these arguments on object declaration.

Answer (score -1):

Here:

```
InteractiveObject interactiveObjects[ 1 ];
```

You're declaring an array of InteractiveObjects, but `InteractiveObject` doesn't have a zero-argument default constructor to create the object with.

Instead, you need to instantiate this at runtime using `new`.